# FullCalendar rendering collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am trying to instantiate a FullCalendar, but when it initially renders, it show up empty/collapsed, like this:
[image]

When I try inspecting the element, it looks like the content should be there.
[image: invisible calendar content]

If I do anything that resizes the window or click any of the FullCalendar button ("Month", "Week", forward/back arrows), the calendar is then re-rendered/re-painted to look like it should:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like something in  your layout. Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: This isn't default behaviour, but you seem to have heavily customised the CSS, so I'd guess that's where the issue is. But there's no code or demo so no-one can say for certain.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl - I changed some things (see my next comment) and it's not happening anymore, so I'm going to hold off on creating a demo.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson - I think it was in a container with a set height that was shorter than the rendering height (although I was allowing for y overflow). Since I moved it out of the modal, I haven't had this rendering issue, but I'll comment back if I figure out what was causing it!